# printing json data in format of key value pair in django

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to print json data in format of key value pair so that i can render them in my html template.

```
def ecpd(request):
    r= requests.get('http://jira.xxx.xxx.com/rest/api/2/issue/key-XXX',auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'),headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})
    jsonDict = json.loads(r.content)
return HttpResponse(jsonDict['fields'])
```

as a response, I am only getting list of Keys in the "fields".
like:customfield_10070customfield_10071customfield_10072customfield_10073customfield_13221customfield_10074customfield_13220customfield_10075.
*I need a key-value pair in dict format.*

Comment: What would be the values?

Answer (score 3):

`HttpResponse`, if passed an iterable, will iterate over it to build the response content. A `dict` is iterable, and iterating over it is actually iterating over the dict's keys. From your problem description, I assume `jsonDict['fields']` is a `dict` indeed.

If you want to return this dict as `json` (ie calling the view with ajax), then you have to dump it back to json and return a proper "json" response. You can do it manually (dumping back to json and setting the proper content-type), or use the builtin `JsonResponse` (Django >= 1.7)

```
r = requests.get('http://jira.xxx.xxx.com/rest/api/2/issue/key-XXX',auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'),headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})
jsonDict = r.json() # requests shortcut
# Django >= 1.7
return JsonResponse(jsonDict["fields"])
# Django < 1.7
data = json.dumps(jsonDict["fields"])
return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

Now if what you want is to render this in a Django template, just pass it to your template's context:

```
r = requests.get('http://jira.xxx.xxx.com/rest/api/2/issue/key-XXX',auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'),headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})
jsonDict = r.json() # requests shortcut
return render(request, "path/to/your/template.html", {"data":jsonDict["fields"]})
```

and in your template:

```
<dl>
{% for k, v in data.items %}:
  <dt>{{ k }}</dt>
  <dd>{{ v }}</dd>
{% endfor %}
</dl>
```

Answer (score -1):

Prior Django 1.7

use

```
def ecpd(request):
    r = requests.get('http://jira.xxx.xxx.com/rest/api/2/issue/key-XXX',auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'),headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})
    response_data = r.content
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

From Django 1.7 Onwards

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

#rest of the views
def ecpd(request):
    r = requests.get('http://jira.xxx.xxx.com/rest/api/2/issue/key-XXX',auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'),headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})
    response_data = r.content
    return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def ecpd(request):
     r= requests.get('http://jira.xxx.xxx.com/rest/api/2/issue/key-XXX',auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'),headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})
    if r.status_code == 200:
         jsonDict = r.json()
         return HttpResponse(jsonDict)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in your post on how it works and why it's a solution.

Comment: Hi Aman. I tried it displays the same thing. I actually want to iterate over "fields" which in turn has key-value pair like {summary:xxx , desc : xxx} and return them as a json object.